# Help me install HP Ink Tank Wireless 410 in Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: printing, hp

Print job is not completing, it shows processing after one print

Comment: please [edit] your question to include steps you took to install the printer. Did you install [HPLIP](https://www.linuxcompatible.org/story/how-to-install-hplip-on-ubuntu-2004-lts/) for example?

Comment: Establish a wireless connection. Read https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSQuickPrintQueues. Printer setup should be completely automatic. No need for HPLIP.

Comment: Closing this question is based on a view that HPLIP is the answer. Whoever did it should become acquainted with driverless printing. This user's printer is capable of that. This post is not a duplicate of the referenced one. Not unless one lives in the dark ages.